# php undefined variable, doesnt get unset

Tags: php, variables, undefined

The variable $WebSiteDirectory never gets unset how ever i still get an error message

the variable gets set in "/../Include/ini.inc.php":

```
$WebSiteDirectory = "mydir\";
$newLine = "<br />";
$phpNewLine = "\n";
```

the place its getting stuffed up is :

```
echo $WebSiteDirectory; // this line is fine 
function theFunction($VAR) {
$dir = $WebSiteDirectory."my other dir"; // this line gets an error
var_dump($dir);
return file_exists($dir);
}
```

not sure there the error if forming. However, i also reuse `$WebSiteDirectory` later on the the program so i know it's not getting unset anywhere. i'm pretty sure im blind

Comment: `global $WebSiteDirectory; $dir=$WebSiteDirectory."my other dir";`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PHP variables outside of a functions scope are not visible.

You must pass in your $WebSiteDirectory into the function as a parameter, or you can use the global keyword

```
function theFunction($VAR){
    global $WebSiteDirectory
```

Please read up a little on variable scope in the PHP manual first as it illustrates some good reasons for and against this method:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

Add Your variables into your function

```
function theFunction($VAR) {

$WebSiteDirectory = "mydir";
$newLine = "<br />";
$phpNewLine = "\n";

$dir = $WebSiteDirectory."\my other dir"; // this line gets an error
var_dump($dir);
return file_exists($dir);
}
```

Or you can initialize this variable into global variable

```
global $WebSiteDirectory = "mydir";
global $newLine = "<br />";
global $phpNewLine = "\n";
```

Then only you can access this variable into your functuion