# return statement not return any value in php function

Tags: php, database, mysqli

Can someone tell me why my return statement is not return any value in data[0] however if i choose to echo it, it shows that there is a value in data[0] but wouldn't work with the return statement.

```
include_once("Init/Initialize.php");

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

    $username = $_POST['username'];

    function username_in_use($username){    


        $query = "SELECT COUNT(`userId`) FROM `users` WHERE `username`=?";

        $statement = mysqli_prepare($dblink, $query);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 's', $username);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($statement);

        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM );

        return $data[0] ;
    }

echo username_in_use($username);

}
```

Comment: when i take the statements out of the function block and replace the return with an echo statement, it displays the result but however with return statement its not displaying any result

Comment: If i also do return $data[0].'string' the string get displayed

Comment: when i check if $data[0] is empty or not, it shows that $data[0] is not empty.

Comment: Are you sure the query is working? It looks like `$dblink` is undefined in that function.

Comment: PHP has a functional scope meaning that variables defined outside of the function are not available within a function and vice versa. Your function has no view on the variable `$dblink` within the function.

Comment: That function has no idea what `$dblink` is. [SCOPE, Scope, scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php undefined variable, doesnt get unset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942909/php-undefined-variable-doesnt-get-unset)

Comment: the query is working as the dblink is defined in initialize.php file

Comment: here is the initialize.php file  <?php
ob_start();

session_start();

$config = parse_ini_file('C:/xampp/config.ini');

require_once('dbConnection.php');

require_once('functions.php');

error_reporting(1);


$init = $config['init'];

$dblink = db_connect();


?>

Comment: @MosesBonji But you don't have `global $dblink;` in the function, so it can't access the variable.

Comment: I don't think it's related to the problem, but it's usually wrong to define functions inside `if` statements. Functions should be defined at top-level of the script, you call them from inside conditional code.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for the observation, i brought the function definition into to if statement for trouble shooting and would return it to my function.php file after am through

Comment: Yeah you guys were correct, the $dblink was not available to the username_in_use() function. as it started working when i declare the dblink inside the function

Comment: I was actually commenting out the //function username_in_use(){ and the closing curly bracket to use echo and that explain why it was working with the echo statement

Comment: You guys made my day and am very grateful to you all as i had been struggling with the problem for 48 hours now. thanks alot every one.

Comment: One more question please, does that mean that for every function i define i have to include the line $dblink = dbconnect() as part of the function definition?

Comment: It would be better to create the  connection once and then pass it  as a parameter to your functions.

Comment: would do just that. Thanks alot@Dont panic